# No HDMI sound on Nvidia card on Ubuntu but no problem winth windows

Tags: nvidia, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

Tested Mint 17,ubuntu 14LTS,kubuntu 16LTS,currently on ubuntu 16LTS.
Nvidia driver installed.

Checked **alsamixer** for muted device & **unmuted** them.

**pavucontrol** shows all HDMI output **unplugged**.

In **Windows** if i install Nvidia driver,HDMI sounds is **okay**.

```
addicted@ADDICTED:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I have disabled inbuilt audio chipset on bios.(also tried audio testing with inbuilt audio on)
Tested audio device mannually with

```
aplay -D plughw:0,3 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav
```

& device 7,8,9.

Sink List

```
addicted@ADDICTED:~$ pacmd list-sinks
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    priority: 9050
    volume: front-left: 65351 / 100% / -0.07 dB,   front-right: 65351 / 100% / -0.07 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 0 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 26.00 .. 371.52 ms
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1>
    module: 6
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "HDMI 0"
        alsa.id = "HDMI 0"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "3"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xf7080000 irq 17"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "10de"
        device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
        device.product.id = "0fba"
        device.string = "hdmi:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "hdmi-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
        device.description = "HDA NVidia Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Nvidia GPU 72 HDMI/DP"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10de0072,10438520,00100100"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
    active port: <hdmi-output-0>
```

lspci -vvnn output

```
lspci -vvnn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller [8086:0100] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8P67/P8H67 Series Motherboard [1043:844d]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snb_uncore

00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port [8086:0101] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 24
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Memory behind bridge: f6000000-f70fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000e0000000-00000000f1ffffff
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA+ MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:02.0 Display controller [0380]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0112] (rev 09)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [1043:844d]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 33
    Region 0: Memory at f7400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Region 2: Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Region 4: I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1c3a] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8 series motherboard [1043:844d]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 34
    Region 0: Memory at f7d28000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579V Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1503] (rev 05)
    DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8P67 Deluxe Motherboard [1043:849c]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 31
    Region 0: Memory at f7d00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Region 1: Memory at f7d25000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Region 2: I/O ports at f080 [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e

00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1c2d] (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8 series motherboard [1043:844d]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Region 0: Memory at f7d24000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1c10] (rev b5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Memory behind bridge: cfb00000-cfcfffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000cfd00000-00000000cfefffff
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1c12] (rev b5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 17
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: f7c00000-f7cfffff
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:1c14] (rev b5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin C routed to IRQ 18
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: f7b00000-f7bfffff
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:1c16] (rev b5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin D routed to IRQ 19
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=05, subordinate=05, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff
    Memory behind bridge: f7a00000-f7afffff
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.6 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge [8086:244e] (rev b5) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin C routed to IRQ 18
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=06, subordinate=07, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000c000-0000cfff
    Memory behind bridge: f7900000-f79fffff
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1c.7 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 8 [8086:1c1e] (rev b5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin D routed to IRQ 19
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=08, subordinate=08, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000b000-0000bfff
    Memory behind bridge: f7800000-f78fffff
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1c26] (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8 series motherboard [1043:844d]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 23
    Region 0: Memory at f7d23000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Z68 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller [8086:1c44] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Z68 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller [1043:844d]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller [8086:1c02] (rev 05) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8 series motherboard [1043:844d]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 30
    Region 0: I/O ports at f0d0 [size=8]
    Region 1: I/O ports at f0c0 [size=4]
    Region 2: I/O ports at f0b0 [size=8]
    Region 3: I/O ports at f0a0 [size=4]
    Region 4: I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
    Region 5: Memory at f7d22000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1c22] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8 series motherboard [1043:844d]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin C routed to IRQ 3
    Region 0: Memory at f7d21000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Region 4: I/O ports at f040 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GM206 [GeForce GTX 960] [10de:1401] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GM206 [GeForce GTX 960] [1043:8520]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 35
    Region 0: Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Region 1: Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Region 3: Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    Region 5: I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at f7000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_361

01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:0fba] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8520]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 17
    Region 0: Memory at f7080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

03:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042 SuperSpeed USB Host Controller [1b21:1042] (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8B WS Motherboard [1043:8488]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17
    Region 0: Memory at f7c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:3118]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 18
    Region 0: Memory at f7b00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    Expansion ROM at f7b80000 [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k

05:00.0 SATA controller [0106]: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB362 SATA Controller [197b:2362] (rev 10) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8P67 Deluxe Motherboard [1043:8460]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 19
    Region 0: I/O ports at d040 [size=8]
    Region 1: I/O ports at d030 [size=4]
    Region 2: I/O ports at d020 [size=8]
    Region 3: I/O ports at d010 [size=4]
    Region 4: I/O ports at d000 [size=16]
    Region 5: Memory at f7a10000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at f7a00000 [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

06:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge [1b21:1080] (rev 01) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 18
    Bus: primary=06, secondary=07, subordinate=07, sec-latency=32
    I/O behind bridge: 0000c000-0000cfff
    Memory behind bridge: f7900000-f79fffff
    Secondary status: 66MHz+ FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: <access denied>

07:02.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6306/7/8 [Fire II(M)] IEEE 1394 OHCI Controller [1106:3044] (rev c0) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Motherboard [1043:81fe]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 32 (8000ns max), Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17
    Region 0: Memory at f7900000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Region 1: I/O ports at c000 [size=128]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: firewire_ohci
    Kernel modules: firewire_ohci

08:00.0 SATA controller [0106]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE9172 SATA 6Gb/s Controller [1b4b:9172] (rev 11) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 88SE9172 SATA 6Gb/s Controller [1043:8477]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 32
    Region 0: I/O ports at b040 [size=8]
    Region 1: I/O ports at b030 [size=4]
    Region 2: I/O ports at b020 [size=8]
    Region 3: I/O ports at b010 [size=4]
    Region 4: I/O ports at b000 [size=16]
    Region 5: Memory at f7810000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512]
    Expansion ROM at f7800000 [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
```

Really Desperate for solution as i want to Kill windows asap.:p
Windows is still installed only because i need to play video

Comment: 'pavucontrol shows all HDMI output unplugged.' Also 'card 0, subdevice 0'.  Your nVidia card is not recognized. Instead of 'subdevice 0' it should be some model number or some name. Go to nVidia site and download the recommended driver (stable) for your card. Uninstall your current nVidia driver and install that one.

Comment: installed 361 version that's recommended i guess.

Comment: No luck, huh? I'm using 361 too. Odd thing , when i'm connecting my smarttv via hdmi, it will only work with hdmi no. 2 (out of 4). I have no ideea why. Did you tried all your hdmi ports? After changing hdmi port, log out (or restart) and log back in, this will restart the pulseaudio and alsa services, and maybe you'll get lucky.

Comment: using gtx 960.It got 1 HDMI ,3 Display port.1 DVI.with `aplay -l` i see 4 HDMI(also in windows i see 4 HDMI).But in alsamixer i see 4 S/PDIF o/p.I never used display port & my screen don't have any(it got DVI,HDMI,VGA,don't know or ever used display port)

Comment: also tried reloading alsa,killing pulseaudio & starting it.